# Hide the iOS/Android URL bar quickly

Tags: javascript, android, ios

I'm attempting to "hide" the URL bar in Safari on iOS (also applies to Android browser). I've come across many variations all doing something like this:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
});
```

This does position the top of the viewport at the top of the screen, and after ~3-5 seconds, the URL bar does go away. However, if you look at the [mobile website for Gmail](https://mail.google.com) or at the mobile [login screen for Facebook](https://m.facebook.com/index.php), you'll see that the URL bar disappears rapidly (less than 2 seconds).

Does anyone know what they're doing to get the URL bar to hide itself rapidly?

This question is close to what I'm after, but it doesn't quite solve my problem: [how to hide URL bar in ipod touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338638/how-to-hide-url-bar-in-ipod-touch) - If you take a look at [iUI demo](http://www.iui-js.org/demo), it appears to also rapidly hide the URL bar.

Comment: Are you doing anything else in load?

Comment: Nope, just the block of code above in the question. I even took a look at some of the Facebook code. From what I could tell, they're doing the above...but there must be something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my full test page that I'm using, I had a few paragraphs of text to make the document longer. This text was causing Safari to display the `Reader` button in the URL bar. Well, apparently, when the `Reader` button shows up, the URL bar doesn't hide itself as quickly as when this button is *not* there.

I couldn't find anything that explains the longer wait (I do think it makes sense), but here's a little more info:

- http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/safari-reader
- https://superuser.com/questions/387572/how-does-safaris-reader-work-and-when-does-it-show-up

Answer (score 0):

does this answer the question for android?

```
$(document).ready(function() { setTimeout(scrollTo,200,0,1) });
```

[Hide the URL bar in Android Webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107812/hide-the-url-bar-in-android-webkit)

Comment: No. It does position the top of the viewport at the top of the screen, as I'm already doing. However, I still see a 3-5 second lag before the URL bar hides itself.